# NFS hangs in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: server, mount, 15.10, nfs

i have problem with nfs in 15.10. Before 15.10 i use 14.04 with nfs shares from my server without problems for years.

But after new Ubuntu 15.10 installation my nfs shares sometimes stop responding. I can't even do ls in directory where shares are mount, because even ls will freeze. I have links from nfs to my home directory and when this happens i can't access my home. I must restart to solve this problem. Even restart is problem, because computer don't restart and i need to use ctrl+sysrq reisub or restart button on pc. I can't find anything useful in logs.

Could you please help, how to discover where could be problem? Or even better do you know where could be the problem? Thank you.

Ubuntu 15.10 client settings

```
/etc/fstab:
192.168.168.123:/sklad/data     /media/bender   nfs4    auto    0  0
192.168.168.123:/safe           /media/safe     nfs4    auto    0  0

Which mount nfs with this settings:
192.168.168.123:/safe on /media/safe type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=0.0.0.0,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.168.123)
192.168.168.123:/sklad/data on /media/bender type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=0.0.0.0,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.168.123)

This works in 14.04 64bit without any problems.

uname -a
Linux fry 4.2.0-18-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:25:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

nfs version
ii  libnfs8:amd64                                 1.9.7-2                                    amd64        NFS client library (shared library)
ii  libnfsidmap2:amd64                            0.25-5                                     amd64        NFS idmapping library
ii  nfs-common                                    1:1.2.8-9ubuntu10                          amd64        NFS support files common to client and server
```

Server settings

```
/etc/exports
/media/     192.168.168.0/24(ro,async,fsid=0,no_subtree_check)
/media/sklad/   192.168.168.14(rw,async,no_subtree_check) 192.168.168.8(rw,async,no_subtree_check) 192.168.168.9(ro,async,no_subtree_check) 192.168.168.6(rw,async,no_subtree_check) 
/media/safe 192.168.168.14(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash) 192.168.168.40(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)

uname -a
Linux bender 2.6.32-42-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 18:57:09 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux

nfs version
ii  nfs-common                           1:1.2.0-4ubuntu4.2                              NFS support files common to client and serve
ii  nfs-kernel-server                    1:1.2.0-4ubuntu4.2                              support for NFS kernel server
ii  libnfsidmap2                         0.23-2                                          An nfs idmapping library
```

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled a Dell Inspiron laptop with Ubuntu 15.10 (64 bit) & hit exactly the same problems with my NFS shares. Each time I tried to access an NFS share, Nautilus would crash along with any other software trying to access that share. Sometimes, even the whole laptop would lock up.

I even activated debugging to a separate logfile (add ***.debug    /var/log/debug.log** to the end of /etc/rsyslog.conf) & used **rpcdebug -m nfs -s proc** to log NFS clientside events - which told me nothing. The logs just stopped as it crashed, but that did make me think that this was happening at a *very* low level.

So, in desperation, I updated the kernel. I had been running **4.2.0-30-generic** but I downloaded & installed **4.5.0-040500rc7-generic** instead.

**This fixed all of my NFS crashes & totally SOLVED my problem...**

So, there you go. I checked in /boot & I had both **4.2.0-30-generic** & **4.2.0-16-generic** there, along with my new **4.5.0-040500rc7-generic** kernel, & it was a clean install only a few days ago. The NFS crashes started as soon as I booted it up after the install, as I tried to copy a file from my NFS share & it instantly crashed. It's crashed ever since, so both those versions of the kernel had the same problem. Thankfully, it all appears to be fixed now, with 4.5 - but I don't know enough about kernel hacking to tell you why...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue starting with 15.04 and still with an upgrade to 15.10. I can see my `nfs` directories initially, but a large file transfer or accessing a large file > 1G will cause a freeze... sometimes the rest of the system will still respond, but the directories involved including my home directories will lock up. I can't do `ls` or open nautilus to browse `nfs` or my home directories. Only thing that seems to work is a reboot.

Client `fstab`:

```
192.168.1.105:/srv/nfs4/MUSIC_PICS_APPS /home/user/MUSIC_PICS_APPS nfs4 user,auto 0 0
192.168.1.105:/srv/nfs4/NEW_MOVIE_MUSIC /home/user/NEW_MOVIE_MUSIC nfs4 user,auto 0 0
192.168.1.105:/srv/nfs4/NEW_LEARNING /home/user/NEW_LEARNING nfs4 user,auto 0 0
192.168.1.105:/srv/nfs4/MASSIVE /home/user/MASSIVE nfs4 user,auto 0 0
```

Server `fstab`:

```
#/dev/sdb1: LABEL="PERSONAL" UUID="1CBCA6E7BCA6BB22" TYPE="ntfs" 
UUID=1CBCA6E7BCA6BB22                       /srv/nfs4/PERSONAL        ntfs-3g defaults,auto,users,rw           0 0
##/dev/sdc1: LABEL="MUSIC_PICS_APPS" UUID="1b0ea35f-ee96-4b5b-9fc8-f76da0c10840" TYPE="ext4" 
UUID=1b0ea35f-ee96-4b5b-9fc8-f76da0c10840   /srv/nfs4/MUSIC_PICS_APPS ext4   defaults,auto,users,rw,noatime    0 1
##/dev/sdd1: LABEL="NEW_MOVIE_MUSIC" UUID="F8ECD8C2ECD87C76" TYPE="ntfs" 
UUID=F8ECD8C2ECD87C76                       /srv/nfs4/NEW_MOVIE_MUSIC ntfs-3g defaults,auto,users,rw           0 0
##/dev/sde1: LABEL="NEW_LEARNING" UUID="3CC03B68C03B2792" TYPE="ntfs" 
UUID=3CC03B68C03B2792                       /srv/nfs4/NEW_LEARNING    ntfs-3g defaults,auto,users,rw           0 0
##/dev/sde1: LABEL="MASSIVE" UUID="96df00c8-4784-46dc-aa88-ff52cffa4e71" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c4eae5c0-8c60-49ae-94be-22856e030401"
UUID=96df00c8-4784-46dc-aa88-ff52cffa4e71   /srv/nfs4/MASSIVE         ext4    defaults,auto,users,rw,noatime   0 1
```

Server `/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/nfs4/PERSONAL          192.168.1.101(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sync)
/srv/nfs4/MUSIC_PICS_APPS   192.168.1.101(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sync)
/srv/nfs4/NEW_MOVIE_MUSIC   192.168.1.101(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sync)
/srv/nfs4/NEW_LEARNING      192.168.1.101(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sync)
/srv/nfs4/MASSIVE           192.168.1.101(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sync)
```